# Core Data: Grouping Entities by Entitiy Attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, aggregate, fetch

I have a simple entity with attributes like this:

```
x       : String
y       : String
category: String
z       : Int
```

Nothing extra. 
I want to fetch my data and group it by category. e.g.:

I want to recieve a dictionary, which looks like this:

```
["Category #1": [Entity], "Category #2": [Entity], etc.]
```

So, basically I want to group my entities by category and give it to me. `NSFetchedResultsController` could do this for me, but I don't wan't to us it in this case. It's init method:

```
init(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest, managedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: String?, cacheName name: String?)
```

Have `sectionNameKeyPath` attribute that is just what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to achieve that, using NSFetchRequest `propertiesToGroupBy` property, but it gives me very limited options or I'm doing something wrong, here is my attempt:

```
let sourcesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
sourcesFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "my valid predicate", false)

sourcesFetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["category","title"]
sourcesFetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
sourcesFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "category", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]
sourcesFetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["category","title"]
```

The result is looks like:

```
["Category #1":"Title1", "Category #2": "Title2"]
```

It's not what I want.

I also tried to use `NSExpression` but I definitely doing something wrong. Great article that introduced me to it: http://www.cimgf.com/2015/06/25/core-data-and-aggregate-fetches-in-swift/

I hope somebody could help me with this "looks trivial" task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to sort by some index that category string contain. You should separate it in a new attribute. And then sort by this index. Or create new entity Category, that will contain title and index and connect with relationship. And again fetch with sort by this relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, already think about it myself, but `NSFetchedResultsController ` can do what I'm need, do you think we cannot do the same without it?

Comment: yes, i did, but i don't won't to use it in this case.

Comment: Try to sort just on categories and obtain sorted array of entities.

Comment: What do you think about separating array to sections in this case, for in loop?